# False or true proof of $x^{2(1-x)}+(1-x)^{2(x)}<1$

Tags: inequality, exponentiation, solution-verification

Sketch of proof :
As the function (see above) is symetric we consider only $0< x < 0.5$ .
We start with two lemma

> > Lemma 1 :
> >     $$x^{2(1-x)}<x$$
> >
> > Lemma 2 :
> >     $$(1-x)^{2(x)}>1-x$$

this two lemma are not hard to show omited .

So we have  $x^{2(1-x)}\neq x$ and $(1-x)^{2(x)}\neq 1-x$ it implies $x^{2(1-x)}+(1-x)^{2(x)}\neq 1-x+x=1$

As the function $x^{2(1-x)}+(1-x)^{2(x)}=f(x)$ is continuous it remains to calculate a value of $f(x)$ to end the proof .

Is it right ?

Thanks in advance for your time and patience .

Comment: The inequality seems to be true for $0\le x\le 1$.  Here is a proof for $0\le x\le 1/4$ (which implies that the inequality is true for $3/4\le x\le 1$ by symmetry).   It remains to show that the claim is true for $1/4<x\le 1/2$ (which also means that the inequality holds for $1/2\le x<3/4$).  The equality cases seem to be $x=0,1/2,1$. 
 $$\phantom{a}$$  By Bernoulli's ineq,
$$(1-x)^{2x}\leq 1-(2x)x=1-2x^2$$
for $0\le x\le 1/2$.  If $0\le x\le 1/4$, we have $x^{-x}\le 1/\sqrt2$ so
$$x^{2-2x}\leq x^{-2x}x^2\le 2x^2.$$
Therefore if $0\le x\le 1/4$, $x^{2-2x}+(1-x)^{2x}\le 2x^2+(1-2x^2)=1$.

Comment: I meant $x^{-x}\le \sqrt2$ in my comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I evaluate the left expression at 3, I get $64+{{1}\over{81}}$

So maybe if you restrict it to $0\le{x}\le1$.  Note that outside that range, the result isn't real unless $2x$ is an integer.

If I evaluate the left expression at 0, 0.5, and 1,  I get 1.

So even restricted to $0\lt{x}\lt1$,
I would say false.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning on inequalities is wrong.

$$4\ne3\land6\ne7$$ but $$4+6=3+7.$$