# Showing the inequality $f(x)=x^{2(1-x)}+(1-x)^{2x}\leq 1$ for $0<x<1$

Tags: derivatives, inequality, exponentiation, jensen-inequality

My proof is not really natural but I think it works.

We want to show [1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=power%20series%20%5CBig%28%5Ccos%5E2%5CBig%28x%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B2%7D%5CBig%29%281%2B%5Cfrac%7B195%7D%7B100%7D%281-x%29%280.5-x%29x%5E2%29%5CBig%29%5E2%2B%5CBig%282%5E%7B2x%7D%281-x%29x%5E%7B2%7D*2%5CBig%29%5E2%2B4%5E%7B1.95%7D%28x%281-x%29%29%5E%7B2.95%7D2):

> Let $0<x<1$ such that  then we have :
> $$f(x)=x^{2(1-x)}+(1-x)^{2x}\leq 1$$

Case $0<x\leq 0.25$

The proof of this case is due to user Batominovski:

By Bernoulli's inequality we have:

$$(1-x)^{2x}\leq 1-2x^2\quad (1)$$

We have also:

$$x^{2-2x}\leq 2x^2\quad (2)$$

Summing $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get the desired inequality.

Case $0.25\leq x\leq 0.49$:

I shall prove it later but we have :

> > Let $0.25\leq x\leq 0.49$ then we have :

$$p(x)=2^{2x}(1-x)x^{2}2\geq x^{2(1-x)}$$
And
$$h(x)=\cos^2\Big(x\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)(1+\frac{195}{100}(1-x)(0.5-x)x^2)\geq (1-x)^{2x}\quad (3)$$

With my work we have :

$$f^2(x)\leq \Big(\cos^2\Big(x\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)(1+\frac{195}{100}(1-x)(0.5-x)x^2)\Big)^2+\Big(2^{2x}(1-x)x^{2}2\Big)^2+4^{1.95}(x(1-x))^{2.95}2\leq 1$$

To show it we can use power series see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=power%20series%20%5CBig%28%5Ccos%5E2%5CBig%28x%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B2%7D%5CBig%29%281%2B%5Cfrac%7B195%7D%7B100%7D%281-x%29%280.5-x%29x%5E2%29%5CBig%29%5E2%2B%5CBig%282%5E%7B2x%7D%281-x%29x%5E%7B2%7D*2%5CBig%29%5E2%2B4%5E%7B1.95%7D%28x%281-x%29%29%5E%7B2.95%7D2)

Case $0.49\leq x \leq 0.5$

On the domain $[0.49,0.51]$ the function $g(x)=x^{2(1-x)}$ is concave or:

$$g''(x)\leq 0\quad (4)$$

So we have by Jensen's inequality:

$$g(x)+g(1-x)\leq 2g(0.5)=1$$

As $f(x)=f(1-x)$ it's proved for $0.5\leq x<1$

Question:

How to show $(3)$?

Thanks in advance!

[1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=power%20series%20%5CBig%28%5Ccos%5E2%5CBig%28x%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B2%7D%5CBig%29%281%2B%5Cfrac%7B195%7D%7B100%7D%281-x%29%280.5-x%29x%5E2%29%5CBig%29%5E2%2B%5CBig%282%5E%7B2x%7D%281-x%29x%5E%7B2%7D*2%5CBig%29%5E2%2B4%5E%7B1.95%7D%28x%281-x%29%29%5E%7B2.95%7D2) Vasile Cirtoaje, "Proofs of three open inequalities with power-exponential functions",
The Journal of Nonlinear Sciences and its Applications (2011), Volume: 4, Issue: 2, page 130-137.
https://eudml.org/doc/223938

Comment: See here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17189

Comment: If you are referring to a “proof of Batominovski” (perhaps in an answer to a similar question?) then please add a link to that proof.

Comment: @MartinR No problem see here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3533874/false-or-true-proof-of-x21-x1-x2x1 . The comments .

Answer (score -2):

Actually there is an easier way. Lets search for the maximum of that function. If its outside of $0$ and $1$ than it should be at the boundaries. (But this is not the case)

1. Differentiate the function.
2. Set the derivative equal to zero.
3. Solve for $x$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I would love to see how you solve $f'(x) = 0$ for $x$