# Refinement of $a^{4b^2}+b^{4a^2}\leq 1$

Tags: derivatives, inequality, exponentiation

As I have almost a proof of this fact [If $a+b=1$ so $a^{4b^2}+b^{4a^2}\leq1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176571/if-ab-1-so-a4b2b4a2-leq1) .I propose a refinement of this fact because we have :

> > Let $0<x\leq 0.5$ then we have :

$$x^{4(1-x)^2}+(1-x)^{4x^2}\leq \left(2^{2x+1}x^2(1-x)\right)^{2(1-x)}+\left(1-2^{2x+1}x^2(1-x)\right)^{2x}\leq 1$$

---

I can show the LHS because we have as first fact :

> > Let $0<x\leq 0.5$ then we have :

$$x^{2(1-x)}\leq 2^{2x+1}x^2(1-x)$$

And :

$$(1-x)^{2x}\leq 1-2^{2x+1}x^2(1-x)$$

For a proof see [Refinements of the inequality $f(x)=x^{2(1-x)}+(1-x)^{2x}\leq 1$ for $0<x<0.5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3853868/refinements-of-the-inequality-fx-x21-x1-x2x-leq-1-for-0x0-5)

So the part I cannot prove is the RHS :

Have you an idea for that ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: So you replace an unsolved inequality by a sharper inequality which you cannot solve either?

Comment: @MartinR I'm not agree the inequality of Michael Rozenberg is solved so I propose another one .

Comment: That's what I said. MR's inequality $a^{4b^2}+b^{4a^2}\leq1$ is unsolved. You ask for a solution to a *sharper* inequality.

Comment: Should $a$ and $b$ be always positive? Otherwise there may be some troubles, e.g.  $a=-1/4$ and $b=5/4$ then $a^{4 b^2} = (-1)^{25/4} = (-1)^{1/4}$

Comment: @guest Yes we have $a+b=1$ and $a,b>0$